# Missing events for models in the "included" section of JSON response in Ember Data

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I use Ember and Ember Data - versions 1.13.x

The models dispatch events as expected, for example "didUpdate" happens when a model gets updated on the server.
My problem is with the "side-loaded" models. I expect "didUpdate" to be fired when a model gets updated by being represented in the "included" section of the JSON response.
The API is compliant with the JSON API standard and in fact the included models are properly updated in addition to the main one. It is only the missing events for them.
Is this a bug or is this the expected behavior?

If this is the "expected behavior" then I would appreciate any feedback on how I could introduce similar "didUpdate" events for models in the "included" part of the JSON response.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So I am going to post my solution to the problem. In addition to the solution I am also providing feedback for Ember Data and JSON API spec. Hopefully these will reach the Ember Data team.

Solution:
I extend the JSONAPISerializer and I overwrite normalizeResponse. This way I can get reference to any "included" section in the JSON response. I pass this reference to my store (see below) so it can use it during the 'push' invocation when this particular response updates underlying models.

```
normalizeResponse: function (store, primaryModelClass, payload, id, requestType) {
  store.setIncluded(payload.included);
  Ember.run.next(this, function () {
    store.setIncluded(null);
  });
  return this._super(...arguments);
},
```

Similarly I extend DS.Store and have my own custom store where I have

```
  setIncluded: function (included) {
    this.set('__included', included);
  },

  getIncluded: function () {
    return this.get('__included');
  },

  push: function (modelNameArg, dataArg) {
    var included = this.getIncluded();
    if (!dataArg && included) {
      data = (Ember.isArray(modelNameArg.data)) ? modelNameArg.data : [modelNameArg.data];
      // track models or rather type/id pairs for which you need to send events after these get processed
      data.forEach(function (item) {
        // track this one ...
      }, this);
      result = this._super(...arguments);
      // fire events for the tracked models
      Ember.run.next(this, function () {
        data.forEach(function (item) {
          // fire event ...
        }, this);
      }); 
      return result;
    } else {
      return this._super(...arguments);
    }
  }
```

FEEDBACK:

1) Ember Data should fire events not only for the main model being updated but for any sideloaded/included models as well.

2) JSON API spec should allow in response to deletions of models to supply sideloaded/included models as for the other operations. Deletions can lead to changes in related models and the API should be able to accomodate this.

3) JSON API spec should allow additional semantics for the sideloaded/included models. It should be possible to determine if the sideloaded/included models represent creation, update or deletion. Currently you could guess if it is creation or update but deletion is not covered at all. An API call for update might delete some related models and the spec should allow to represent such deletions in the sideloaded/included section.